# Odd Python behaviour I don't understand

Tags: python, append

When I run this code, I expected all 4 scenarios to produce the same answer, yet scenario 4 produces a different one, please help me undertand why this is, or is it a bug?

```
class myclass():
def __init__(self, test=[]):
    self.test = test
def mymethod(self, content):
    self.test = self.test + [content]
def myothermethod(self, content):
    self.test.append(content)

print('scenario 1')
x = myclass()
print('x: ', x)
print('x.test: ', x.test)
x.mymethod(123)
print('x.test: ', x.test)

print('scenario 2')
x = myclass()
print('x: ', x)
print('x.test: ', x.test)
x.mymethod(123)
print('x.test: ', x.test)

print('scenario 3')
y = myclass()
print('y: ', y)
print('y.test: ', y.test)
y.myothermethod(123)
print('y.test: ', y.test)

print('scenario 4')
y = myclass()
print('y: ', y)
print('y.test: ', y.test)
y.myothermethod(123)
print('y.test: ', y.test)
```

And the output is:

```
scenario 1
x:  <__main__.myclass object at 0x7f904c2fa940>
x.test:  []
x.test:  [123]
scenario 2
x:  <__main__.myclass object at 0x7f904c2fa160>
x.test:  []
x.test:  [123]
scenario 3
y:  <__main__.myclass object at 0x7f904c2fa940>
y.test:  []
y.test:  [123]
scenario 4
y:  <__main__.myclass object at 0x7f904c2fa190>
y.test:  [123]
y.test:  [123, 123]
```

I understand that .append only appends the reference, but in scenario 4 when the entire class is newly reinstantiated, why does is it already include 123 in the .test variable list, rather than the class's default of an empty list?

Comment: This is a quirk of Python, default arguments are evaluated *once* at definition time, you are re-using the same list object

Comment: idiomatic workaround is to use `None` as the default, then you can do `self.test = test if test is not None else []`